# Vue - Vuex: store not updating when calling action from a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, store

I am pulling my hair out over this. I am a Vue noob and am trying to build a User Selector.

The User Selector component is a child component that is supposed to display all users in a  then I have an @change handler to update the currentUser variable in the vuex store.

I think I am using actions and mutations correctly but for some reason it won't set the currentUser to the payload.

UserSelector.vue

```
<template>
  <select class="user-selector" v-model="currentUser" @change="handleChange($event)">
    <option v-for="user in users" :key="user" :value="user">User {{ user }}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UserSelector",
  methods: {
    handleChange(event) {
      this.$store.dispatch("setCurrentUser", event.currentTarget.value);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    users() {
      return this.$store.getters.users;
    },
    firstUser() {
      return this.users[0];
    },
    currentUser: {
      get: function() {
        return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
      },
      set: function(newCurrentUser) {
        this.$store.dispatch("setCurrentUser", event.currentTarget.value);
      }
    }
  },
  updated() {
    const { firstUser } = this;
    if (firstUser) {
      this.$store.dispatch("setCurrentUser", firstUser);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and my store.js is the following:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: {},
    users: [],
    currentUser: 0
  },
  getters: {
    todos(state) {
      return state.todos;
    },
    users(state) {
      return state.users;
    },
    currentUser(state) {
      return state.currentUser;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setTodos(state, payload) {
      state.todos = { ...payload };
    },
    setUsers(state, payload) {
      state.users = [...payload];
    },
    setCurrentUser(state, payload) {
      state.currentUser = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setTodos(context, payload) {
      context.commit("setTodos", payload);
    },
    setUsers(context, payload) {
      context.commit("setUsers", payload);
    },
    setCurrentUser(context, payload) {
      context.commit("setCurrentUser", payload);
    }
  }
});
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? If I console.log the payload in setCurrentUser in mutations, it is correctly passing the new user key however after calling

```
state.currentUser = payload
```

the value of the currentUser in state remains as its default, which is 0. When I debug with with Vue dev tool, I can also see that the currentUser in the state remains unchanged.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is conflict between `v-model` and `@change` handle. Please try changing v-model to `:value` and remove get set in computed:

```
<select class="user-selector" :value="currentUser" @change="handleChange($event)">
  <option v-for="user in users" :key="user" :value="user">User {{ user }}</option>
</select>

  computed: {
    currentUser: {
      return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Or just remove `@change` handle and leave `v-model` as it is